# Has there ever been non-electoral political decisions made via coin toss?

Tags: political-history

I'm thinking of something like this: there are three parties, A, B and C, with leaders Alice, Bob and Charlie. Parties A and B control roughly 30% of the seats each, while C controls roughly 40%. Alice & Bob both detest C, so they form a coalition to take power. However both of them want to be prime minister. They can't figure that one out, so they flip a coin and the winner becomes prime minister.

Has this ever happened? It sounds really random, but something similar [famously happened in the Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostles#Replacement_of_Judas_Iscariot), and I'm wondering if anyone (especially religious people who think God directly intervenes in life) has done this to settle disputes.

I'm aware that there've been many cases of tied elections being settled by coin tosses. I'm not interested in those - I'm only interested in cases where a decision not directly related to tied elections was made via coin toss. Another example could be, I don't know whether to vote to support the construction of this dam or not, so I flip a coin.

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia articles [Coin flipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_flipping) (section on politics) and [Applications of Randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applications_of_randomness#Political_use) (section on political use)? There are quite a few examples there.

Comment: @LarsBosteen thanks for link, I was clearly searching for the wrong terms. Suggest writing into an answer, although I would prefer a modern-day political example (didn't see any in the links).

Comment: I've had a look and haven't found anything not mentioned in the Wiki articles. I wouldn't rule out some major political decisions being made this way, but I guess that those who did toss a coin thought it would be unwise reveal / admit that a major decision was made this way.